# Trigger onBlur on multiple elements as a single unit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two inputs that together form a single semantic unit (think an hours and minutes input together forming a time input). If both inputs lose focus I want to call some Javascript function, but if the user merely jumps between those two, I don't want to trigger anything.

I've tried wrapping these two inputs in a div and adding an onBlur to the div, but it never triggers.

Next I tried adding onBlurs to both inputs and having them check the other's :focus attribute through jQuery, but it seems that when the onBlur triggers the next element hasn't received focus yet.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

EDIT: Someone questioned the purpose of this. I'd like to update a few other fields based on the values contained by both these inputs, but ideally I don't want to update the other fields if the user is still in the process of updating the second input (for instance if the user tabs from first to second input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var focus = 0;
$(inputs).focus(function() { focus++ });
$(inputs).blur(function() {
    focus--;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!focus) {
            // both lost focus
        }
    }, 50);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but since you can only ever have one focused, you might as well use `true` and `false`.

Comment: If you use a boolean flag, you rely on the event firing order to an extent.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it should work, although it is more trouble than I hoped it would be :(

Comment: The question is, did the focus had the chance to fire before the timeout runs. With non-zero timeout it's probably guaranteed, with zero depends on the JS engine internals, which I'm not that interested in to know intimately.

Answer (score 4):

I made a working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/bs38V/5/

It uses this:

```
$('#t1, #t2').blur(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(!$('#t1, #t2').is(':focus')){
            alert('all good');
        }
    },10);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to check the `relatedTarget` of the blur event. As stated in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget) this will be the element which is receiving the focus (if there is one). You can handle the blur event and check if the focus has now been put in your other input. I used a `data-` attribute to identify them, but you could equally well use the `id` or some other information if it fits your situation better.

My code is from an angular project I've worked on, but the principle should translate to vanilla JS/other frameworks.

```html
<input id="t1" data-customProperty="true" (blur)="onBlur($event)">
<input id="t2" data-customProperty="true" (blur)="onBlur($event)">
```

```
onBlur(e: FocusEvent){
    const semanticUnitStillHasFocus = (val.relatedTarget as any)?.dataset?.customProperty === "true";

    // Do whatever you like with this knowledge
}
```

Answer (score -4):

What is the purpose of this behavior ?
The blur event triggers when a field looses focus, and only one field can gain focus at a time.

What you could do, in case of validation for instance, is to apply the same function on blur for both the fields and check the values of the fields altogether.

Without a context, it is difficult to help you more.

d.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Just to give an example of why this behaviour might be useful, my scenario is that I'm wanting a user to input a what3words address in 3 separate textboxes. The address is optional, but a partial address is invalid. I want to validate that either all 3 inputs contain a word, or they are all blank. I don't want the validation to fire when the first input blurs, because the user hasn't had a chance to type in the other 2 words at that point. I want the validation to fire when the user moves away from all 3 inputs.

Comment: I'm truly sorry my answer couldn't help you @Tim. I don't think it deserved a downvote though. I understand your situation, I don't have a solution for it though. Good luck.